# How to save a JSON formatted aata into an R object

Tags: json, r

I have a string of JSON formatted data and I'm simply trying to save this as a dataframe.  Here's my JSON data:

```
newobject <- 
{
  "data": [
    {
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "https://api.nike.com/v1/me/sport/activities/8102000000014097347280007666912117966998"
        }
      ],
      "activityId": "8102000000014097347280007666912117966998",
      "activityType": "RUN",
      "startTime": "2015-07-25T13:27:52Z",
      "activityTimeZone": "America/Anguilla",
      "status": "COMPLETE",
      "deviceType": "SPORTWATCH",
      "metricSummary": {
        "calories": "1012",
        "fuel": "3338",
        "distance": "13.059499740600586",
        "steps": "0",
        "duration": "1:05:27.000"
      },
      "tags": [],
      "metrics": []
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "/v1/me/sport/activities/RUNNING?count=1&access_token=Qr7kEcwD6bpfxy2mJ1yH8uGBGfdY&offset=2",
    "previous": null
  }
}
)
```

When I try to save this to an object in R, I get an error:

## ERROR: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: You have an unmatched parenthesis at the end that is suspect. The JSON between the outer curly braces is valid.

Comment: I dont think this question is off-topic. Its about converting a json object to a data.frame in R. Why this would be a "a simple typographical error"?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to define your object as a string in R, just use simple quotes...

```
newobject <- 
'{
  "data": [
    {
      "links": [
        {
          "rel": "self",
          "href": "https://api.nike.com/v1/me/sport/activities/8102000000014097347280007666912117966998"
        }
        ],
      "activityId": "8102000000014097347280007666912117966998",
      "activityType": "RUN",
      "startTime": "2015-07-25T13:27:52Z",
      "activityTimeZone": "America/Anguilla",
      "status": "COMPLETE",
      "deviceType": "SPORTWATCH",
      "metricSummary": {
        "calories": "1012",
        "fuel": "3338",
        "distance": "13.059499740600586",
        "steps": "0",
        "duration": "1:05:27.000"
      },
      "tags": [],
      "metrics": []
    }
    ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "/v1/me/sport/activities/RUNNING?count=1&access_token=Qr7kEcwD6bpfxy2mJ1yH8uGBGfdY&offset=2",
    "previous": null
  }
}'
```

After that, you can convert the string into a data frame using the `jsonlite` package (`install.packages("jsonlite")`).

```
library(jsonlite)
df <- fromJSON(newobject)
```

Then if you run `df$data` you get your data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm now having an issue trying to save this to a .csv.  Here's my code: 

`df <- fromJSON(newobject)`

#this is a list 
`class(df)`

#this is now a dataframe
`class(df$data)`

#save as its own object
`newdf <- df$data`

#attempt to write to .csv
`write.csv(newdf,file="Nike+ Dataframe.csv")`

...I'm getting the error message: 

_Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed_